# Perl Getopt modules

Tags: perl, getopt

I am new to Perl. I am trying to understand the [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt%3a%3aLong) module and I have read materials online as well as books. Nothing is 100% clear to me hence this question.

I will be calling the command line in the following formats

```
script -m file
```

or

```
script -v hostname -m file
```

How can I accomplish this with [`Getopt::Std`](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt%3a%3aStd) or [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt%3a%3aLong)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use either.

However, I'd advise you use [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) and [`Pod::Usage`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Usage qw(pod2usage);

GetOptions(
    'm=s'    => \my $filename,
    'v=s'    => \my $hostname,
    'help|?' => \my $help,
    'man'    => \my $man,
) or pod2usage(-verbose => 0);
pod2usage(-verbose => 1) if $help;
pod2usage(-verbose => 2) if $man;

# Fake Parameter validation
pod2usage("$0: No filename specified.\n") unless $filename;

print "Hostname = '$hostname'\n";
print "Filename = '$filename'\n";

1;

__END__

=head1 NAME

yourscript.pl - does something

=head1 SYNOPSIS

./yourscript.pl

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item --m

Filename, for some reason.

=item --v

Hostname, maybe make this -h so it's not confused with version flags?

=item --help

Print this summary.

=item --man

Print the complete manpage

=back


=head1 DESCRIPTION

This does stuff.... and other stuff

And this is all there is to say about it

=head1 AUTHOR

Written by You
```

I would advise against your flag choices though.  It's often sufficient to just pass the filename as a loose parameter to a script instead of requiring a flag.  Then just pull it from `@ARGV` after calling your GetOptions.  As for `-v` for hostname, that's typically used to check a version of a script.  Instead I'd use `--hostname` or `-h`.

Comment: `-h` is pretty widely used as `--help` in *nix, so I wouldn't recommend using it for hostname. Of course, being limited to a single character makes it tough to come up with a good alternative.